# Jquery(ajax) PHP search results not displaying in search_results div under form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, dom

For a website I'm making for school, I'm trying my hand at using Jquery extensively for the first time, and even though I managed quite a bit so far, I'm stuck at two (most likely related) problems.

I'm aware that the upcoming case is somewhat long, but I feel it's necessary to submit all relevant code for everyone reading this to get a good image of what is happening.

Basically, the website is one index.html file, with the CSS thrown in, a few buttons, and one div with the ID content. I use this code to make this work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($('#content').innerHTML == " "){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#content').load('main_text.html');
            });
        }
    </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
            $(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceURL+"");
        }
    </script>
```

Then there is one content page, named search.html, which only contains a form that submits a search string to a search.php page (through ajax) that should then place the search results immediately back into a div called search_results in that same search.html file. The jquery that I use for this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#search_results").slideUp(); 
            $("#search_button").click(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                ajax_search(); 
            }); 
            $("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                ajax_search(); 
            }); 

        }); 

        function ajax_search(){ 
            $("#search_results").show(); 
            var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 

            $.post("Functions/search.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
                if (data.length>0){ 
                    $("#search_results").html(data); 
                } 
            }) 
        } 
    </script>
```

The issue that I'm having is as followed:
Before I had the first line of code: if ($('#content').innerHTML == " "){; implemented, I would open the site, main_text.html would nicely be loaded in, I could navigate to other subpages fine. But typing in something in the form field in search.html did not display any results (just typing should already trigger the function). When I hit the search button on this form, instead of seeing query results, the main_text.html file load again in the #content div. This made me assume that perhaps, somehow, that the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#content').load('main_text.html');
    });
```

was being called again unwanted. Hency why I implemented that check for whether innerHTML existed.

However, now, when I first load the page, the #content div does not load any initial content at all. (The section on the webpage just becomes black, like my page background) I have to click any button to get some content loaded again in my main content div. Also, when I now go back to the search.html, the typing anything to get results, like previously, still does not work. If I now hit the search button, I get the initial result again of what I'd see when I just opened the page: a blacked out #content div.

So somehow, the biggest issue is in the fact that the jquery to get results from my PHP do not seem to work. My problem with the content.innerhtml check might well be obsolete if the issue with the searchresults not displaying in the #search_result div on the search.html is fixed.

Anyone have any idea's what I could do to fix this. Or otherwise, what other approaches I could take for the kind of website I'm making. Since I'm trying to learn jquery here, better approaches are always appreciated, I'd rather learn myself doing this the right way and all. :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try removing the space between the quotes? Replace `" "` with `""` and check out if the code is working and let us know. :)

Comment: using jquery, you want $('#content').html() == "" not $('#content').innerHTML == " " in your if.

Comment: Yes sorry, "" was actually my first try, forgot to mention that. In then started troubleshooting with other options, amongst others the " ". All give the same result. (No result, that is.)

Comment: @Mason81 tried .html() now instead of innerHTML, but this sadly gives the same result. So basically, the findings of that IF statement come back as being FALSE, and that's why the main_text.html is not loaded. Not sure why not. This is how the line looks like a bit below for the content div:
<div id="content"></div>

Comment: Have you tried putting you if inside the document.ready? Like this:
$(document).ready(function(){if($('#content').html()==''){$('#content').load('main_text.html');}});

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('#content').innerHTML == " "){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#content').load('main_text.html');
        });
    }
</script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
        $(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceURL+"");
    }
</script>
```

In the above, you are testing to see if there is a `space` in the innerHTML of the element with an `id of content`.

jQuery uses .html() or .text() to make comparisons against the data being held within a container, so if you want to maintain using jQuery principles, change this line. Going along the same thought process, you are preparing an `IF` statement on an `element` before the `document is actually ready and loaded.`

You should move the document.ready function to the `outside` of the `if statement`. This will allow you to ensure that the element is available at DOM, and you can indeed perform checks against this element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    if ($('#content').html("")){
        $('#content').load('main_text.html');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Also, while being readily provided and fully functional, I would recommend starting off using `$.ajax` instead of `$.get / $.post`. I have personal preferences as to why I think this, but I won't go into that, it's just that, *personal*.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Functions/search.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: "search_term="+search_val,
  success: function(data){
    if (data.length>0){ 
      $("#search_results").html(data); 
    } 
});
```

Lastly, you should be using the `GET method` and NOT the `POST method`. Based on REST/SOAP practices, you are retrieving data from the server, and not posting data to the server. It's best practice to follow those two simple ideas. This isn't because web servers will have a difficult time interpreting the data; but, instead, it's to prepare you for working on larger scale application deployment, or future team-environments. This way everyone on the team has an expectation as to what method will be used for what purpose.

Anyway, long story short, you also leave `semicolons` off of the end of your `closing })` brackets. While this is not an issue, nor will it cause flaws in your development, `coding is all about uniformity`. You've used the closing `;` everywhere else, so try and maintain that same uniform design.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. The first part worked perfectly. Just moving the document.ready outside the if statement (and switching to .html()) was all it took. Actually seems rather obvious, as you can't possibly check if some content exists, when it may not even have been loaded yet, haha.

Comment: Also, tried doing the ajax request not with .ajax, as opposed to .post and also used the GET type (and adjusted my query file to listen to a GET input.) However, I still have the same strange quirk, that as soon as I hit search, I get thrown back to where it seems as if the website just loaded again (main_text.html loaded in the content div again). Any ideas?

Comment: When you say, 'as soon as I hit search' you're implying that the `preventDefault()` is not working as intended and the 'search button' is replicating a `form-submission-page-reload` effect?

Comment: Yeah, correct. Although I didn't know anything about a form-submission-page-reload effect. But yes, somehow the preventDefault() is being ignored in the searchbutton.click function. Any other way to get around to fixing this?

Comment: Is the `search button` an actual `<button>`? Is it wrapped inside a `form`? if so, use `$('#formID').submit(function(e) e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Are you sure you want to do if($('#content').html(""))... and not if($('#content').html() == "") ... The one you have up there will set the html of #content to an empty string every time, rather than compare it with an empty string.